# Rate app on android market inside the app

Tags: android, google-play, rating

Android Market ratings are important to app developers. I've often seen applications saying something like "Please consider rating us" and then have buttons for "Ok take me to market" / "Not right now".

What I would love to do is show the user a rating bar (like this http://kozyr.zydako.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/defaultRatingBar.png) inside my app and let user do the rating inside my app instead of sending him off to the market.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The rating is done through market app so that ratings can be trusted. If apps were allowed to handle the rating themselves, then developer would give his app very high ratings.
So there is no way you can handle the rating yourself.

Comment: +1 Totally agree with your answer and @vertti if this possible then we developer can give 1 million rating to our developed applications.

Comment: Yeah, should have guessed as much.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to do so. Sorry.